# Delete not saved object doesnt invoke exception

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, dao

I'm writing tests for my `Dao Spring` application. I found out that when I delete not saved items no exception is invoked as I'd expect, I've got no idea why.

Model:

```
@Entity
public class Ingredient {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String condition;
    private int quantity;

    public Ingredient() {

    }
}
```

The `Dao` implementation:

```
@Override
public void delete(Object o) throws DaoException {
    try {
        Session session = mSessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.delete(o);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new DaoException(ex, String.format("Problem deleting %s object (delete method).", o));
    }
}
```

And my test, expecting `DaoException`:

```
@Test
public void testDeleteNotSavedThrowsDaoException() throws Exception {
    Ingredient ingredient = new Ingredient("Not saved ingredient","", 1);
    ingredientDao.delete(ingredient);
}
```

Comment: As a side note, I would recommend that you look at Spring Data JPA. That entire method can be autogenerated for you by thoroughly tested and widely-used libraries.

Comment: Thanks, but I have to write own CrudDao, its part of my course test

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hibernate's Javadoc for [Session#delete(Object)](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#delete-java.lang.Object-) states:

> Remove a persistent instance from the datastore. The argument may be an instance associated with the receiving Session or a transient instance with an identifier associated with existing persistent state.

So it's not an error to pass in a transient entity (as you do). Also, the `Session#delete` method does not declare any exceptions, so it's not defined what happens when you pass in an entity with an ID that does not exist in the DB. As you can see - nothing happens - you requested the entity not to exist in the DB, it's not there to start with, so no reason to throw an exception (according to Hibernate, at least).

Compare this to the basic SQL `DELETE FROM X WHERE ID = Y` - this does not check if a record with `ID=Y` exists, it will succeed either way (updating 0 or 1 rows).

**UPDATE** after realizing the passed in transient entity has `null` ID.

I've dug into the sources of Hibernate 5.2.2 `Session` and it seems that if the passed in entity has no ID, no `DELETE` query is even performed on that entity's table.

See `DefaultDeleteEventListener#onDelete(DeleteEvent, Set)`:

```
if (ForeignKeys.isTransient( persister.getEntityName(), entity, null, source ) ) {
    // yes, your entity is transient according to ForeignKeys.isTransient
    deleteTransientEntity( source, entity, event.isCascadeDeleteEnabled(), persister, transientEntities );
    return;
}
```

Now

```
protected void deleteTransientEntity(
        EventSource session,
        Object entity,
        boolean cascadeDeleteEnabled,
        EntityPersister persister,
        Set transientEntities) {
    LOG.handlingTransientEntity(); // Only log it
    if ( transientEntities.contains( entity ) ) {
        LOG.trace( "Already handled transient entity; skipping" );
        return;
    }
    transientEntities.add( entity );
    // Cascade deletion to related entities
    cascadeBeforeDelete( session, persister, entity, null, transientEntities );
    cascadeAfterDelete( session, persister, entity, transientEntities );
}
```

this will just print `"HHH000114: Handling transient entity in delete processing"` in the logs and do nothing with the entity (however, it will cascade the deletion to the related entities if there are any - not your case).

So again - it's OK to pass in a transient entity without an ID - it will simply not run a `DELETE` on the DB.

Comment: Ofcourse method declares throwing DaoException when any problem with session happen: try {
        Session session = mSessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.delete(o);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new DaoException(ex, String.format("Problem deleting %s object (delete method).", o));
    }

Comment: "...or a transient instance with an identifier associated with existing persistent state." But how that new item assosiated with EXISTING PERSISTENT state? Id of item is null.

Comment: @zzheads - about not throwing the exception I meant `Session#delete`, not your `Dao#delete`. About the ID - I thought the `1` in `new Ingredient("Not saved ingredient","", 1)` is the ID (you didn't post this constructor), but now I assume it's the quantity, right?

Comment: @zzheads - see my update showing what happens when there is no ID in the entity you pass in

Comment: Thanks, Adam, I beleive I got it )

Answer (score 0):

And that was an answer, Adam, there was no exception, because id of my new, not saved item was null. When I set id to value which not persist in DB exception was thrown.